# Replace an item in an array by a link

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "foo";


var arr= ["the","ff","gg"];

arr[1]='<a href = "www.google.com">str</a>'
```

Here in line 3 it prints "str" but I want to print "foo".
So how can I do this?

Comment: assign it the variable str and not the string.

Comment: Does shouting required for this question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want:

```
arr[1] = '<a href = "www.google.com">' + str + '</a>';
```

Inside of the string literal, `str` doesn't hold any meaning.

And to print you might want to use `console.log`.